# Newlines being added to Bamboo artifacts used in deployment project

Tags: powershell, deployment, tortoisesvn, bamboo

I've just set up a project's deployment to our stage server. I have a powershell script on the remote server that is copying files from the bamboo artifacts to a specific folder on that same server. The folder they are being copied to uses TortoiseSVN as it's source control. Once the files are copied over all of my .js,.css,.html files are showing up as being modified in TortoiseSVN when only a couple have truly been modified. Using diff on some of the files the only difference between the new files and the previous is that newlines are being added to the end of every file.

My main question is if Bamboo modifies some project's files during the artifact building process or if there is another explanation for why these files are showing up as being modified.

**Edit:** As a side note, I deployed a different project to the same server using the same script and no newlines were present in any of the files. This project was smaller in size than the first project mentioned.

Comment: Which cmdlets did you use to copy the artifacts from bamboo to the tsvn directory?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I used `Copy-Item -Path $sourceDirectory\* -Destination $targetDirectory -recurse`